# Order Matrices or Dists by dimnames

Tags: r, matrix, row, col

I am trying to perform Mantel tests for which I have a genetic distance matrix and a physical distance matrix. Due to how these matrices were generated, their 'order's are jumbled with respect to one another. Surprisingly, I am finding it difficult to order these matrices by their row/column names (i.e. the dimnames or dimension names). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a dummy sample set:

```
d1 = matrix(c(0,1,2,1,0,3,2,3,0),nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(d1) <- c("A","B","C")
colnames(d1) <- c("A","B","C")

d3 = matrix(c(0,.2,.3,.2,0,.1,.3,.1,0),nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(d3) <- c("C","A","B")
colnames(d3) <- c("C", "A","B")
```

This creates two related matrices. Lets pretend that d1 contains info on how far apart different strains of a species (e.g. A, B, C) where isolated from one another, while d3 contains a pairwise genetic difference between these same isolates. I need these two matrices to be in the same order to perform the mantel test.

When I try using order, I loose the matrix:

```
d3[order(rownames(d3))]
[1] 0.2 0.3 0.0

d3[order(as.data.frame(rownames(d3)))]
[1] 0.2 0.3 0.0
```

Comment: Did you mean `d3[order(rownames(d3)), ]`?  Or `d3[order(rownames(d3)), order(colnames(d3))]` to order both the rows and columns to match `d1`.  But since they share the exact same names, you don't really need `order()` either.  You can do `d3[rownames(d1), colnames(d1)]`

Comment: Duplicated. Asked before on SO. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785998/r-how-can-i-reorder-the-rows-of-a-matrix-data-frame-or-vector-according-to-ano), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508352/how-to-sort-a-matrix-in-r-row-wise) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339725/sorting-matrix-by-column-names).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the duplication - I had come across many posts but could not seem to get what I was looking for...turns out I was simply forgetting the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard points out, I was missing a comma.

```
d3[order(rownames(d3)), order(colnames(d3))]
```

does exactly what I want!